# How to set indent distance when saving a dict to a JSON file in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, json.net

I use Visual Studio 2022 and download Newtonsoft.Json in NuGet package manager, my dict like:

```
var param_dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "config_path", "D:\WORK_2023\Helloworld in C" },
};
```

Now I want to save it as a JSON file, so I tried this code:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param_dict, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(param_file_path, json);
```

The problem is how to change the `Formatting.Indented` value, I found its default value is 1, but I want to change to 4, but it cannot work if `Formatting.Indented = 4;`.

Or I need to change other namespace, like Json.NET?

Comment: This is not related to WPF, so I removed this tag and added "json.net" instead.

Comment: I found an alternative method, `param_dict_json = param_dict_json.Replace("  ", "\t");`

Comment: @4daJKong, it is wrong. You may broke string serialization. What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes,you are right, I fogot this point, I just want to knoe if there is some solution can solve this quesion by Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: @4daJKong, look below, I have prepared solution for `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonTextWriter` with appropriate `Indentation` property:

```cs
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(param_file_path);
using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
jsonWriter.Indentation = 4;

var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings{ Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, param_dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting.Indented - only specifies whether formatting should be used. In fact, the introduction of this enumeration at the present time is nonsense. Usined a bool flag instead would be sufficient. Perhaps the original intention of the package developers was to have a wider range of values.

What you need, I think, is the Indentation property.

See [Formatting Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm) and [JsonTextWriterIndentation Property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_Indentation.htm).